# Oracle 9i: How can I determine, using metadata, whether or not an index is clustered?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

The question pretty much sums this up, but I'll provide some more details.

I can *almost* safely assume that any primary key index in an Oracle database is clustered. But I'm not one to assume. Besides, a user might have created a clustered index that *wasn't* the primary key. If that's the case, I'd really like to know.

So, in the interests of being *really, really* thorough, I'd like to remember (not that I forgot or anything), how to determine from the Oracle metadata, whether or not an index is clustered.

(And, per usual, Google was like rooting through a landfill, looking for the vintage Action Comics #1 that your mom through out because she thought it was useless at the time.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not have the concept of "clustered indexes" as SQL Server does.  In general, Oracle table are "heaps" with the data stored in no particular order.  There is a special type of table called an [INDEX ORGANIZED](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref1047) table, which is (as its name suggests) a table that is organised like an index.  However, in Oracle most tables would **not** be index organized - whereas my understanding is that most tables in SQL Server **do** have a clustered index.

Do not be tempted to declare all your Oracle tables as index organized in an attempt to emulate SQL Server; what is right for one DBMS is not necessarily right for another.  I suggest you read the [Oracle Database Concepts guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm) to get to know how Oracle works.

Index organized tables are identified by IOT_TYPE = 'IOT' in ALL_TABLES and USER_TABLES.

Answer (score 2):

What is known as a clustered index in SQL Server world is in Oracle world called an Index Organized Table. Table metadata is available in the all_tables or user_tables system views [described here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091). My guess after skimming that link is that you can determine that a table is index-organized by checking whether the IOT_TYPE column is non-null.